# How to relate the definition for entailment, with soundness and completeness?

Tags: definitions, logic, knowledge-representation, norvig-russell, symbolic-ai

Is it fair enough to say for a language model, φ, which makes certain variable A true, and if φ also makes another variable B true, then we can conclude:

> A ⊨ B

And for a certain inference calculus c, from which B can derive A,

> A ⊢ cB

The logic is sound if `A ⊢ cB` is true, which also makes `A ⊨ B` true.

The logic is complete if `A ⊨ B` is true, which also makes `A ⊢ cB` true.

Comment: Can you please put your **question** in the title? A question is something like this "What is the color of the sky?"

Comment: Changes made to the title. @nbro

Comment: Can you please define those symbols `⊨` and `⊢`? How are they related to "soundness", "entailment" and "completeness"? Given that you tagged the post with [tag:norvig-russell] I suppose you're reading their book. Which section and page of that book?

Comment: ⊨ refers to entailment, ⊢ refers to inference; please refer to Pg: 241- 243 for the proper illustration of these symbols and definitions( I replaced α, β with A, B).@nbro